# Turn list of words in string form into list

Tags: python, string, list

```
list13 = ['USA','UK','China']
type(list13)
str
```

Currently, the list13 is in string format. How do I turn this into python list type?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must be seeing something that can't be reproduced in python 3.7:

```
>>> list13 = ['USA', 'UK', 'China']
>>> type(list13)
<class 'list'>
```

nor python 2.7:

```
>>> list13 = ['USA', 'UK', 'China']
>>> type(list13)
<type 'list'>
```

because both of them gives me the type list for the exact same code you described.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about types : Python handles types for you. A list is always a list. Actually `type(list13)` should return `<type 'list'>` not `str` and `type(list13) == list` should return `True` (unless you have a variable named `list`).